# iptables - how to allow internet but block subnet?

Tags: iptables

How to isolate one computer in network

```
IP to isolation: 10.17.15.99 
Subnet: 10.17.15.0 
Gateway: 10.15.15.1
```

Tried:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.17.15.99 -d 10.17.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

I need to access to internet from the .99 ip, access to from subnet to it, but drop all connections to subnet from the IP

Answer (score 0):

You must accept the traffic between your gateway and your computer .99 with a rule like this:

```
INPUT -s 10.17.15.99 -d 10.17.15.1 -j ACCEPT

INPUT -s 10.17.15.1 -d 10.17.15.99 -j ACCEPT
```

And this rules must be before your rule which drop all other traffic from and to this computer.